# Series convergence of $\sin(\frac \pi{n^2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know how, **using the limit comparison test**, to show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n^2}\right)$$ converges.

(The ratio test in inconclusive. And the integral test shows convergence; but I know this only because I used a calculator because the antiderivative is not an elementary function.)

So if $$a_n= \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n^2}\right)$$, then I need to find a convergent series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$$ such that $$0 <= a_n <= b_n$$

Comment: Hint: $0 < \sin(x) < x$ for $x>0$

Comment: @universalset: $\sin\left(\frac32 \pi\right) = -1$

Comment: True, we need $x < \pi$ as well. :)

Comment: Except that $a_1=\sin(\pi)$.  I really need to get a life

Answer (score 2):

Note that $0\le\sin(x)\le x$ for $0\le x\le\pi$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac\pi{n^2}\right)\le \pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}
$$
so the series converges by comparison with the series on the right (which converges by the $p$-test).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $0< \sin(x) < x$ for all $x \in (0, \pi)$. Hence, we have
$$0 <\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n^2}\right) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\pi}{n^2} = \dfrac{\pi^3}6$$

Comment: It would help very slightly if you stated that all the terms in the sum on the left were non-negative

Comment: @Henry Done, Your Honour.

Comment: $\sin\left(\frac32 \pi\right) = -1$ and I know I should not be so pedantic.  Sorry

Comment: @Henry Done, Your Honour.

Comment: First take absolute series of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} sin(\frac{\pi}{n^2})$, so all term are positive and we can use$sin x\leq x$ and also comparison theorem.since absolute series converges original series also converges

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Limit comparison test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n^2}\right)}{1/n^2} = \pi
$$
is finite and nonzero, either both series converge or both diverge. The harmonic series definitely converges, and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n^2}\right)$ also converges.